# How to create Data layer in caffe?

Tags: python, c++, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I have a caffe code in Python version.
That python code has a `data layer` like

```
name: "hidden_seed"
type: "NumpyData"
top: "hidden_seed"
```

I like to crate in c++ caffe as

```
layer{
    name: "hidden_seed"
    type: "Data"
    top: "hidden_seed"      
}
```

My query is how to create a data layer with size 300 x 250 with 0 value initialized.

I looked at data layers in caffe and available data layers are

```
Layers:

    Image Data - read raw images.
    Database - read data from LEVELDB or LMDB.
    HDF5 Input - read HDF5 data, allows data of arbitrary dimensions.
    HDF5 Output - write data as HDF5.
    Input - typically used for networks that are being deployed.
    Window Data - read window data file.
    Memory Data - read data directly from memory.
    Dummy Data - for static data and debugging.
```

Which one is suitable for the Data layer what I like to have and how to initialize 0 value for each cell?

Comment: what is a NumpyData layer? what branch of Caffe are you using?

Comment: Apollocaffe (https://github.com/Russell91/apollocaffe)

Comment: found it [here](https://github.com/Russell91/apollocaffe/blob/master/include/caffe/data_layers.hpp#L336-L359).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like [`"DummyData"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/dummydata.html) layer will do the job for you:

```
layer {
  type: "DummyData"
  name: "hidden_seed"
  top: "hidden_seed"
  dummy_data_param {
    shape { dim: 300 dim: 250 }  # your desired data shape
    data_filler { type: "constant" value: 0 } # fill with all zeros
  }
}
```